# How can I get headers inside controller's constructor in ZF2?

Tags: php, constructor, zend-framework2

I am trying to get the header in constructor of the Controller Class like

```
$this->params()->fromHeader();
```

But its not working is there any other way to get header in constructor

I am passing the userId in header so i wants that in Constructor will it be possible?

Thank you.

Comment: no it returns null array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to grab user id from custom header. Short answer is yes, it is possible. But doing this inside the `constructor` may not the correct way since all MVC controllers instantiated by [ControllerManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/ControllerManager.php).

What you need is implementing `onDispatch()` method inside your controller to check header value just before dispatching actual action.

Try this:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * On dispatch event
     *
     * @param  MvcEvent $event
     */
    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $headers = $e->getRequest()->getHeaders();
        if($headers->has('user')) {
            // User header is provided.
            $header = $headers->get('user');
            // ... here you can do what you want with this header.
        }

        // Don't forget to trigger parent's dispatch.
        return parent::onDispatch($e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not test but try this:

```
$headers = $this->getRequest()->getHeaders();
$user_param = $headers->get('user');
$user_value = $user_param->getFieldValue();
```

Comment: this is the output Zend\Http\Headers Object
(
    [pluginClassLoader:protected] => 
    [headersKeys:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [headers:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: I mean it does not provide header that i have passed

Comment: check your http request or ajax request with firebug and check if it really sends headers

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have just found it using this

```
$headers=apache_request_headers();
```

Comment: I will not reccomend this: seems apache specific and also if you're using a framework better use built in framework functions

Comment: $headers = $this->getRequest()->getHeaders(); is not giving me anykind of headers